# PyTango Device with 'externally' updated attributes

Tags: python, events, tango-controls

Let's say you have a hardware device that sends you updates at more or less random intervals and that a client wants to receive events every time this happens. How would you write a PyTango (The Python wrapper for the [Tango controls library](http://www.tango-controls.org/) `PyTango.server.Device` class that simulates this using a thread that pushes new attribute values?

Answer (score 2):

The answer seems to be

1. Calling the `PyTango.server.Device` method `set_change_event()` to tell Tango that the device is taking care of its own change event pushes, without needing to use a polling loop.
2. Using `Pytango.sever.Device` method `push_change_event()` from the update thread. Seems thread-safe so far, have not seen any malarkey even with very high update rates. Would be nice if someone could confirm that.
3. Also caching the updates so that clients polling the attribute get the correct value and timestamp. This seems a bit redundant, is there a better way?
4. Do not set up polling on the attribute since it can cause client polling to get stale values (Tango seems to cache attribute values from polls in a way that I can't quite figure out).

Herewith an example (python 2.7) server using the externally updated `randomnumber` attribute

```
import time
import threading
import random

from PyTango.server import server_run
from PyTango.server import Device, DeviceMeta
from PyTango.server import attribute, command

from PyTango import AttrQuality


class ExternallyUpdated(Device):
    __metaclass__ = DeviceMeta

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExternallyUpdated, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._randomnumber = (0, 0, AttrQuality.ATTR_VALID)
        # Tell Tango that we don't need a polling loop, we'll 
        # push change events explicitly
        self.set_change_event('randomnumber', True)

    @attribute(label="Random Number", dtype=int,
               # Enables update events for absolute changes >= 1
               abs_change=1)
    def randomnumber(self):
        return self._randomnumber

    def init_device(self):
        super(ExternallyUpdated, self).init_device()
        self.t = threading.Thread(target=self.update_loop)
        self.t.setDaemon(True)
        self.t.start()

    def update_loop(self):
        while True:
            try:
                new_number = random.randint(0, 10000)
                ts = time.time()
                sleeptime = random.random()*10
                print ('Timestamp: {:.5f}    New value: {}    sleeptime: {}'
                        .format(ts, new_number, sleeptime))
                # Need to cache the value so that clients can poll the attribute
                self._randomnumber = (new_number, ts, AttrQuality.ATTR_VALID)
                self.push_change_event(
                    'randomnumber', new_number, ts, AttrQuality.ATTR_VALID)
                time.sleep(sleeptime)
            except Exception:
                logger.exception('Exception in update loop')
                time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server_run([ExternallyUpdated])
```

And an example client below, assuming you exported the device as `so_example/external/1`. It should print a message every time randomnumber is updated.

```
import time
import logging

import PyTango


logger = logging.getLogger()
logging.basicConfig(
        format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(module)s - '
        '%(pathname)s : %(lineno)d - %(message)s',
        level=logging.INFO)

device_name = 'so_example/external/1'

td = PyTango.DeviceProxy(device_name)
attr_name = 'randomnumber'

# Set up a listener
def printer(event_data):
    try:
        print event_data # A PyTango.EventData instance
    except Exception:
        # Not handling exceptions seems to break the event update loop. Or I was
        # doing something else stupid, must still investigate :)
        logger.exception('Exception while handling event, event_data: {}'
                         .format(event_data))
poll_event_id = td.subscribe_event(
    attr_name, PyTango.EventType.CHANGE_EVENT, printer)

# Do something that blocks here, or just run in an interactive session
# time.sleep(60)

# This is how you would unsubscribe from the events.
#td.unsubscribe_event(poll_event_id)
```

Comment: A useful description of the high level Python server API is here: http://www.esrf.eu/computing/cs/tango/tango_doc/kernel_doc/pytango/latest/tep/tep-0001.html